# Change text color of selected <li> item

Tags: css

I'm trying to change the text color of "Sale" item, but not a phone number with only CSS. I can't edit HTML code.

[image]

```
.menu.left a:first-child {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

[image]

Results in both yellow & red

---

```
.menu.left li:nth-child(2)`
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

[image]

Results in only yellow background

---

Do you have an idea how to solve this?

Comment: keep the yellow there ,then add red to this `.menu.left li:nth-child(2) a` ---> you need to target a not li

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can target the `<li>` or the `<a>`
 in this case i target the second li and then the a so the font changes to red.
If you only target the li, the font wont change to red.

Hope this is what you were looking for. Happy to explain or help in a better solution if needed.

> Example targeting the `<a>`

```css
.menu.left li:nth-child(2) a{
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu left">
  <li>
    <a href="#">1231233123</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sale</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

> Example only targeting the `<li>`

```css
.menu.left li:nth-child(2){
  background-color: yellow;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<ul class="menu left">
  <li>
    <a href="#">1231233123</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="#">Sale</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**Comment by OP**

"Thank you, Gerardo, your solution worked very well. I run into trouble though with mobile version of this link. Maybe you could take a look? codepen.io/anon/pen/xYJKRW "

On your comment you added a codepen, where you have the same mistake. You are trying to target the `<li>` when you have to target the `<a>`  try this:

```
[data-mobile-dropdown-rel="sale"] a {
  color: red;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Gerardo, your solution worked very well. I run into trouble though with mobile version of this link. Maybe you could take a look? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/xYJKRW

Comment: @J.Baptiste edited my answer with the answer to your new problem. Please try to keep one question per question. And dont forget to upvote if you can.

Comment: Thank you for help, good man. I would upvote it one hundred times if I could. Because I'm using a simplified version of my code here, I run into another issue, as all children of this one are red too. Could you find a sec for this? https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RQBbJX

Comment: @J.Baptiste add ``>`` between the data selector and the ``a``. like this ``[data-mobile-dropdown-rel="sale"]>a``.

Answer (score 0):

```
.menu.left li:nth-child(2) a {
    background: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

Comment: don't show me the doc i know it ;) simply try it and see what happen ... a inside li and last-of-type will target all of them

Answer (score 0):

Add `color:red;` to `.menu.left li:nth-child(2)` and keep the `background:yellow;` where it is now. Your trying to change the font color of the `<a>` tag not the `<li>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is supposed to work:

```
ul.menu li:nth-child(2) a {
    background-color: yellow;
    color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For changing color of `<a>` you have to change color of `<a>` directly. Otherwise it won't work. In this case you have to change color of `<a>` not `<li>`. That is why it does not work.